# How to check email and username

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Trying to create a REST authentication system using Google Cloud Functions and Firebase. The Firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) say:

> To achieve this, you must create a server endpoint that accepts sign-in credentials—such as a username and password—and, if the credentials are valid, returns a custom JWT.

I see that I have to do something like:

```
let uid = 'some-uid';

admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
  .then(function(customToken) {
    // Send token back to client
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
  });
```

but wondering the best way to verify email/password validity from the login form and get the uid (all in Cloud Functions) to then send into `createCustomToken()`?

Comment: This is a rather broad question. Verifying/validating an email address could involve a lot of work, depending on how much you want to make sure the user is who they say they are.  I suggest making an attempt, then posting a question the describes what your strategy is and where you got stuck in the process.

Comment: The user is in Firebase authentication-- does that simplify things at all?

Comment: If you're using Firebase's email and password authentication, then you don't need any custom auth solution.  Just use the SDK to sign them in and it will do all the work.

Comment: If you're instead trying to create a username+password authentication method, have a look at this example: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/username-password-auth

Comment: Thank you all! I realized I was overcomplicating matters and have opted for another approach entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments-- I realized I was overcomplicating matters and have opted for another approach entirely. Thanks all!